# unable to display the dataframe using .show() in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The code as follow:

```
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.sql import *

spark=SparkContext()

sc=SQLContext(spark)

valuesA = [('Pirate',1),('Monkey',2),('Ninja',3),('Spaghetti',4)]

TableA = sc.createDataFrame(valuesA,['name','id'])

valuesB = [('Rutabaga',1),('Pirate',2),('Ninja',3),('Darth Vader',4)]

TableB = sc.createDataFrame(valuesB,['name','id'])

TableA.describe('name').show()
```

The error as follow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-dcdbe2628b72> in <module>
1 TableA.describe('name').show()
```

Comment: TableA.describe(['name']).show()

Comment: @Toshirro - Which version of spark you are using? Are you using any any Hadoop distribution or have spark on local machine?

TableA.describe('name').show()

This is working for me. I have Spark 2.3.1

Comment: pyspark   2.4.0  data frames are generated with that above code. The only problem was If I use any methods of pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame it is not working      But when I generate the dataframes using files show method is working properly.

Comment: I am using winutils

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use describe function like this:

```
TableA.describe(['name']).show()
```

Comment: That was the same thing what I did

Comment: I can see in official doc, that you should use [].